# downgrade the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, downgrade

I have some business to downgrade the kernel in Ubuntu 9.10.

I downgraded from kernel 2.6.31-14 to 2.6.26.8. Then
I got the following error in my boot process :

```
warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
use --subdomainfs to override
```

What does that mean anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: My gut says that Ubuntu doesn't support kernel versions lower than what the distribution was designed for (it probably applies to other distros as well). Some program wants to use a kernel feature that is only in 2.6.31 (or anything higher than 2.6.26), so it will not work.

Comment: Do you have any ext4 formatted partitions?